# Need help counting different values in the same table in SQL

Tags: sql, count

I'm new to SQL and I'm having trouble with a count query. I want to count the number of results that return a value and also return a second count if the value is null.

Here is what I have so far. If anyone can help I would appreciate it. Thanks.

```
Select
    Sum(Case When Column name = '!NULL' Then 1 Else 0 End) as [Policy ID],
    Sum(Case When Column name = 'NULL' Then 1 Else 0 End) as [No Policy Id]
    --Count(*) as [Total]
From 
    table.name
Where 
    columnname >= '2016-01-01'
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` instead of checking nulls with equality:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN Column_name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Policy ID],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Column_name IS NULL     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [No Policy Id]
--COUNT(*) AS [Total]
FROM table.name
WHERE columnname >= '2016-01-01'
```

In SQL the value `NULL` means "unknown" and hence comparing a column value against it using `=` also yields an unknown result.  Instead, use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

@TimBiegelesien's answer is right the only thing I would add/suggest would be if ColumnName contains an Empty string ('') and you want to count it as `NULL` you could do something like this:

```
Select
Sum(Case When LENGTH(ColumnName) > 0 Then 1 Else 0 End) as [Policy ID],
Sum(Case When LENGTH(ColumnName) < 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) as [No Policy Id]
--Count(*) as [Total]
From table.name
Where columnname >= '2016-01-01'
```

Note in some rdbms LENGTH is actually LEN

```
Select
Sum(Case When LEN(ColumnName) > 0 Then 1 Else 0 End) as [Policy ID],
Sum(Case When LEN(ColumnName) < 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) as [No Policy Id]
--Count(*) as [Total]
From table.name
Where columnname >= '2016-01-01'
```

This will still work even if the datatype is numeric (int, bigint, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using two separate queries:

```
    SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN LEN(columnname) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Policy ID] FROM table.name
WHERE columnname >= '2016-01-01';

    SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN columnname IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
 AS [No Policy ID] FROM table.name
WHERE columnname >= '2016-01-01';
```